# How to provide index for the dynamically created textboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to access text entered on dynamically created text boxes which were added to my asp table (tblCompanyDetails). I have given the textboxes id's ranging from 1 to 30(tCC1, tCC2....so on)

I want to do something like this to get the value.

```
for (index = 1; index <= 30; index++ )
{
   txtCCID = "tCC" + index.toString();
   txtCC = document.getElementById('<%=tblCompanyDetails.FindControl(txtCCID).ClientID%>').value;
}
```

But this is not possible as I have to enter a string in FindControl. Is there some way to provide indexed id's in the method?

Comment: `document.getElementById(txtCCID).value;`? Why do you need ASP.Net when JavaScript can do it for you?

Comment: @c.P.u1 no, since in asp.net for dynamically created controls, the page assigns a different id than one you provide. If this doesnt work out, I'll have to use id's like ContentPlaceHolder1_tCN1 as the id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following: When creating your textboxes in code behind add the attribute "name" with unique names instead of the ID..

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("name", "tb" + counter);
```

.. and when you're trying to get your values in javascript use:

```
document.getElementsByName("tb" + counter)[0].value
```

to get your value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (index = 1; index <= 30; index++) {
  txtCCID = "tCC" + index.toString();
  txtCC = $('[id$="' + txtCCID + '"]').text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the IDs for your TextBoxes, also set their [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) properties so that your JavaScript has a predictable ID to use to access them.